# Simple grouping equations

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, parametric-functions

I'm new in the Mathematica world. A very basic question.
I have been using the command `Eliminate` on a set of equations as follow:

```
eqns = {
   AA == 2 a + 4 b + 45 c + 5,
   BB == 4 a + 45 b + 31 c + 78,
   CC == 0.23 a + 0.4 b + 4.35 c + 0.12,
   DD == 0.73 a + 0.2 b + 43.455 c + 3.12,
   c == 43.5 AA + 34 b + 32};

eqns2 = Eliminate[eqns, c]

(*  a == 7.47796 + 18.6712 CC - 0.263852 DD && 
 AA == 1.27831 + 3.96322 CC + 0.121389 DD && 
 b == -2.58212 - 5.07913 CC - 0.154479 DD && 
 BB == -14.035 - 162.875 CC - 7.13412 DD  *)
```

So far so good. Everything works as expected.
However now I would like to split the set of equations, and apply the `Eliminate` command on their combination, like:

```
   eqnsMain = {AA == 2 a + 4 b + 45 c + 5, BB == 4 a + 45 b + 31 c + 78, 
       CC == 0.23 a + 0.4 b + 4.35 c + 0.12, 
       DD == 0.73 a + 0.2 b + 43.455 c + 3.12};

    eqnsAdd = {c == 43.5 AA + 34 b + 32}

    eqnsRed = Eliminate[{eqnsMain, eqnsAdd}, c]
```

Unfortunately the `Eliminate` command returns the error:

```
Eliminate::elist: "List encountered during logical expansion of {AA==5+2\ a+4\ b+45\ c,BB==78+4\ a+45\ b+31\ c,CC==0.12 +0.23\ a+0.4\ b+4.35\ c,DD==3.12 +0.73\ a+0.2\ b+43.455\ c}"
```

Why is it not working properly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `eqnsRed = Eliminate[Flatten@{eqnsMain, eqnsAdd}, c]`.

Comment: That is working! Thanks. Why did I need the Flatten ? What does that error mean?

Comment: Look those functions ([`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) and [`Eliminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html)) up in the documentation. You should be doing this anyway! `Eliminate` wants a list of logical expressions, not a list of lists. `Flatten` fixes that.

Comment: Also look at [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
fulleq=Append[eqnsMain, eqnsAdd];
```

And then

```
Eliminate[fulleq, c]
```

Using the {} parenthesis to fuse them would require Flatten on the result, as Mathematica will combine the vectors, not their components.